# Using jQuery UI Resizable on a rotated image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This question have been asked before but haven't been answered successfully.

I am using jQuery UI Resizable in order to let the user resize images. I want to let the user rotate an image and then resize it, the problem is that when the image is rotated, the mouse coordinates of the Resizable are being rotated as well.

For example, if I rotate the image 90 degrees, the left-right mouse movements resize the image vertically instead of horizontally.

The jQuery UI Resizable should be modified somehow to support rotation.

Does someone knows how to solve it or has a plugin for resizing+rotating?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jKYkT/51/) link, this will help you fix the problem if you rotate the image 90 degrees, the left-right mouse movements resize the image vertically instead of horizontally.
i added the image like this.

```
 <div id="resizable"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image"/></div>
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't understand how is it working in the Fiddle, because I have also tried to use jQueryRotate and on my website it doesn't work that way and the resizing just go crazy when I try to resize after 90 degrees rotation...